# Split textarea into different textboxes with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input, split, textarea

I'm quite inexperienced with JavaScript, but need a solution for a fairly simple problem.

I would like to be able to enter information in an html textarea, press button and split the contents of the textarea into different textboxes. Maybe visualizing it will make it more clear:

So i would like to go from this:

```
<textarea>
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
<textarea>
```

To this:

```
<input type="text" value="Line 1" />
<input type="text" value="Line 2" />
<input type="text" value="Line 3" />
```

Thanks!

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your HTML is as follows

```
<textarea id="text_area">
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
</textarea>

<div id="input_text"></div>
```

This Javascript will create input elements based on the contents of your text area

```
// Destination element to contain the input elements
var destination = document.getElementById('input_text');

// Contents of textarea
var content = document.getElementById('text_area').innerHTML;

// Array containing each line of the textarea
var lines = content.split('\n');

for(i = 0; i <= lines.length; i++)
{
    if(lines[i] != '' && lines[i] != undefined)
    {
        // Create input element
        el_name = 'input_' + i;
        el = document.createElement('input');
        el.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        el.setAttribute('name', el_name);
        el.setAttribute('value', lines[i]);

        // Append input element to destination
        destination.appendChild(el);
    }
}
```

Working example here http://fiddle.jshell.net/AvA3a/